# Graphical annotation with media metadata?

Tags: media, metadata, photos

Is there a tool that allows graphical annotation of media data (e.g. JPEG images) where the annotation is embedded into the media data's meta data?
For instance, I would like to point out, i.e. highlight and label elements of the picture without modifying the actual picture.
Think of the annotation bubbles in Youtube.

Maybe there is a way to embed SVG data into the images metadata that can be overlayed in the respective viewer application?

The second best approach is to create a seperate SVG file and either render it on top of the image, or using the SVG and just linking the image file.

There are probably better approaches, but this apparently has not caught on in the mainstrem.

Comment: Part of the FOAF project: embedding images in svg used as metadata: http://www.rdfweb.org/2002/01/photo/ Have not found an application that stores SVG overlays in XMP metadata yet.